# Error in Firefox: try compress image in base64

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, canvas, base64

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fenex/j6aLzut0/)

I make a factory `ImgCompression`. The factory get link to image or encoded image in base64 format.
The Factory compresses an image and returns base64 of a compressed image.

In Chrome works fine.  Both buttons give the expected result.
But FF doesn't want work if input image is base64 format.

FF didn't trigger event "onload" of image object (if input image is base64 only) (78 line in the jsfiddle). I resolved this problem: I made variable `resolved`, then I make additory call `compress` function.

Now, I show another error in console (on line 73):

```
Exception { message: "", result: 2147746065, name: "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE", filename: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/", lineNumber: XX, columnNumber: 0, inner: null, data: null }
```

What's wrong in the code?

Comment: The assumption that [Firefox does not trigger onload when data-uri is used](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/ahzb5cmv/) does not seem to be correct.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg, yep, but in my example it doesn't work...

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg, hm, now it's [working](http://jsfiddle.net/Fenex/Lwzn2qzf/)... okey... .

But another error?

Comment: Stop. [Last example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fenex/Lwzn2qzf/) is working... But I don't understand why

Comment: Seem to work in FF (looking in console). You could compare the first and last code using a diff to see what parts has changed. Also look for asynchronous issues (using a timer is a no-no with image loading).